# golang separation of concerns vs usability

Tags: inheritance, go, module, architecture, structure

I have always struggled keeping go modules neatly separated and avoiding cyclic dependencies.

Right now I have code like this:

```
    package chain


type Block struct{
    Content []byte
    Number int
}

var Chain []Block = make([]Block, 10)

func AddBlockToChain(block Block){
    // do some checks
    //...
    // add to chain
    Chain[block.Number] = block
}

func GetBlock(number int) Block {
    // do some checks
    //  ...
    // get from chain
    return Chain[number]
}
```

To achieve consensus I need some extra info on the block. The info may be different depending on which consensus algorithm I use. I want the consensus algorithm to be interchangeable (e.g. by flag on start up).

It would be convenient to store the info as fields in the block, so that when I call GetBlock(3) or get a block from anywhere else I can not only access the block but also the info on what state of consensus this block is in at the moment.

On the other hand I wanted to keep data that is only relevant for a certain consensus algorithm separate from basic block data - maybe even in a separate package.

**How should I design my program? Where should I keep data relevant for a certain consensus algorithm?**

Some background info:

I am trying to build a block chain application from scratch. I have a "chain" module responsible for storing blocks of data and a "consensus" module responsible for creating consensus between multiple peers running an instance of my program on what that data is.

Comment: You are mixing up different types from different packages: The `Block` from one package is totaly unrelated to the one from the other package: You'll have to decide whether you want a chain of chain.Block or consensus.Block. You cannot magically convert between them.

Comment: In Java I could. I could have an array of the super class containing instances of the subclass. When I want to access a method of the subclass I could convert the object from the array to an object of subclass and access the subclasses methods / fields. Maybe there is no way to do this in go without putting both structs in the same module like in ΔλЛs answer.

Comment: Given that there is no super-/sub-class relation in Go it is pretty obvious that a solution based on super-sub-class behaviour cannot work.

Comment: In the end for me this is about separation of concerns. I thought I could solve this using modules and struct embedding. I'm open to any other solution, though.

Comment: @Volker sorry that my question wasn't clear. I edited it, so that it asks in a more general way about where to keep my data instead of insisting on struct embedding or inheritance equivalents.

Comment: If you want interchangeability in Go, use interfaces. Embedding gives you composition *only*, not polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`consensus.Block` and `chain.Block` are two separate types but since you are embeddding `chain.Block` in `consensus.Block`, you can access one from another.

Just pass `consensus.Block` in `AddBlockToChain()`:

```
`func AddBlockToChain(block consensus.Block)`
```

and then access it by: `block.Block`

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ChainBlock struct {
    id int
}

type ConsensusBlock struct {
    ChainBlock
    idCons int
}

func printChainBlockId(consBlock ConsensusBlock) {
    fmt.Println(consBlock.ChainBlock.id)
}

func main() {
    test := ConsensusBlock{
        ChainBlock: ChainBlock{
            id: 42,
        },
        idCons: 44,
    }

    printChainBlockId(admin)
}
```

Comment: This way the two structs can't be in separate modules. Is my assumption wrong that a part of a program that should be completely interchangeable should be a separate module?

Comment: I think that in this case the assumption is wrong - I would create two files (chain.go, consensus.go) in a same package.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a viable approach. From [organizing go code](https://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code): "The http package comprises 17 go source files (excluding tests) and exports 109 identifiers, and the hash package consists of one file that exports just three declarations. There is no hard and fast rule; both approaches are appropriate given their context."

Answer (score -1):

For completeness I want to add a solution that keeps the code and data of the consensus algorithm in a different package than the block and chain code:

Add an extra field to the block like this:

```
Extra []byte
```

Then keep the extra data needed for a consensus algorithm in that algorithms package in a struct and encode it to json or some other format to store it in the extra field.

This solution keeps separate concerns separate. The chain would not make sense without a consensus algorithm, but they can look very different and might need different data. This way different algorithms can store different data.

I did not go with this solution however, because it just seemed simpler to keep all the code in one package as @syntagma suggested.